# Firebase How to get friends info

Tags: firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I have retrieved friends UIDs, What's the best way to observe their info like name, photo etc.. ?
now UidArray holding friends uids, Should i loop for each uid to show their info on Tableview ?

```
let userIdArray = self.UidArray
for id in userIdArray {
    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else {
            return
        }
        let displayN = dictionary["displayname"] as? String
        let Uid = dictionary["uid"] as? String
        let ImgUrl = dictionary["urlToImage"] as? String

// Append results to another array, reload table view if loop is done.
```

User Model:

```
class Userr: NSObject {
    var displayname: String?
    var email: String?
    var gender: String?
    var uid: String?
    var urlToImage: String?
}
```

I just want to fetch data once. I don't want to hit the database each time cell displays by scrolling.

I would like to know what's the best way to get friends info based on array of their uids?

Comment: It's impossible to really answer this without more context, including what your model looks like.

Comment: @mchandleraz thanks for answering, User model just a simple vars to handle the info, I just edited my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A for loop isn't needed and is very overkill as the `.childAdded` that is used in the observe method for Firebase will call the function as many times as there are users, just like a for loop.

```
 func handleFetchAllUsers(_ completion: @escaping ([User]) -> ()) {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {

    var data: [User] = []

    let reference = Database.database().reference().child("users")

        reference.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

            guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] else { return }

                    let username = dictionary["username"] as? String
                    let name = dictionary["name"] as? String
                    let email = dictionary["email"] as? String

                    let user = User()
                    user.name = name
                    user.username = username
                    user.email = email

                    data.append(user)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        completion(data)
                    }

            }, withCancel: nil)

        }, withCancel: nil)
    }
}
```

You'd call the function like so:

```
var users: [User] = []

handleFetchAllUsers { (user) in // USER IS THE ARRAY OF USERS RETURNED FROM THE FUNCTION
    self.users = user
    self.collectionView.reloadData() // IF YOU'RE USING A UICOLLECTIONVIEW.
}
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing this code, But this isn't what i want, I did observe to retrieve friends uids [ClickHere](https://i.gyazo.com/81eef225c7eb66956d514e09d757e165.png) Now these uids saved in UidArray, How can i observe their profile like name,photo etc with once fetch? Could you edit your answer and show how to observe users info by specific array of uids?